# Proving that a quotient ring is not an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

> $F$ is a field. Let $n≥2$ be an integer. How do you prove that the quotient ring $F[X]/(X^n)$ is not an integral domain?

I'm trying to prove that the quotient ring has zero divisors, but I have no idea how to go about this. Thank you!

Comment: In your quotient, $X^n=0$ but $X \neq 0$.

Comment: Definitions are your friends.  An integral domain is without "zero divisors".  Look it up and see if you are able to attack the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This quotient ring has a nilpotent element: the class of $X$. A  non-trivial nilpotent element is a zero-divisor.